# Could you help me set up my CI URI routing?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I can't seem to get my routing to work correctly. Right now to reach my main page I need to go to `www.website.com/core` I would like this to be only `website.com` to get to the core.

The second issue I am having is I con not being able to retrieve any css and other files stored in the assets folder. Could you please take a look at my configs and tell me which parts I should adjust? I don't even mind moving the assets folder to a different place on the server, I just really want to get this to work.

the hierarchy on to access CI is as follows

```
(root)/www/application/OBS/controllers...
```

My css, js and other assets are stored in

```
(root)/www/assets/OBS/css/style.css... //example rout to css
```

In CI I am trying to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/OBS/css/core_css.css" />
```

to link the styles and assets and

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('detail/'$id) ?>">
```

to link to functions from views

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the CI's config I have set the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'website.com/core'; //core is used as home/main
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And finally in the CI's index.php I have set:

```
$application_folder = 'application/OBS';
```

Thank you all for reading and in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

set your `base_url` to `website.com` only

```
//application/config/config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'website.com';
```

Then on `routes` set the default controller to `core`

```
//application/config/routes.php
$route['default_controller'] = "core";
```

Comment: nope :( nothing has changed. still no CSS and I still have to go to `website.com/core` to get to the main view. Something I should try next?

Comment: Opps. EDIT: My bad that fixed the main page issue. I am now on the core controller just by going to `website.com`. What should I do about the file references now?

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane when you say file references is it the link to the `assets` ?

Comment: can you share the link