# Remove "index.php" from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this link

> localhost/MySite/queues/index.php

index.php has been removed using .htaccess and I got URL as follows.

> localhost/MySite/queues

Now the problem is, when I use segment in my index function like this:

queues.php --> controller

```
function index($sgmnt = 'test'){
   $this->load->view('queues_view/'.$sgmnt);
}
```

I want to have this link

> localhost/MySite/queues/test

NOT

> localhost/MySite/queues/index.php/test

or I can still type

> localhost/MySite/queues/index.php/test

but URL must show only

> localhost/MySite/queues/test

Comment: I would suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255164/could-you-help-me-set-up-my-ci-uri-routing, it is a question asked a few moments ago but it provides an example of a .htaccess file which will be needed if you are using apache

Comment: No @micb its not the typical remove index.php thru .htaccess.
here is different by using segment in index function.
it's not another function im calling it's still index but with segment on it.

Answer (score 0):

With the above config setting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can take advantage of htaccess.open htaccess and add these lines in to that. i hope it will work(`http://localhost/MySite/queues/test`).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^MySite/queues/test$ /MySite/queues/index.php [L]
```